# Removing 0 from float when length = 4 and replacing NaN with average value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe which has for example:

```
df = [  A  
7280.0         
7330.0  
635.0  
540.0  
     NaN ]
```

What I would like to do is remove the last 0 (from 728**0** and 733**0**) and then replace NaN with average of the values (in this example (728 + 733 + 635 + 540) /4 = 659). What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: What would happen for values like `1234` or `1230.4` ?

Comment: Why not from 540? (I am trying to understand the criterion for removing the 0.)

Comment: "Cast to integer & remove last zero" is an odd request and doesn't make a lot of sense.  What are you actually trying to do?  Are you trying to scale down numbers over 1000?  Will the values you want to truncate always be in the same positions?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh there are no values that don't have 0 at the end. Fourth 0 is an error in the dataset, that needs to be removed. Values should be int and they should not go above 1000.

Comment: @DYZ Fourth 0 is an error in dataset, that needs to be removed.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething I am trying to remove the fourth 0 in values over 1000, as they are an issue in a dataset, they should always be less than 1000. Once I have them, I am using average of all values to fill in the NaNs.

Comment: @M.M. Do you just want to remove zeros or are you trying to trim all values over 1000?  Does 1234.0 get to live (as what?)?  Treating numbers as numbers rather than strings of digits is generally preferable.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething trying to remove 0 only. There is no value 1234.0, there are only 3 digit values , and some of them have added 0 in the end (Which is how they become 4 digit values).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need filter by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and apply floor division by `10`. Last [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html):

```
df.A = df.A.mask( df.A // 1000 > 0, df.A // 10)
df.A = df.A.fillna(df.A.mean())
print (df)
       A
0  728.0
1  733.0
2  635.0
3  540.0
4  659.0
```

Thank you [DYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130244/removing-0-from-float-when-length-4-and-replacing-nan-with-average-value-panda/41130328?noredirect=1#comment69465268_41130328) for another solution:

```
df[df.A>1000]/=10
df.A.fillna(df.A.mean(), inplace=True)
print (df)
       A
0  728.0
1  733.0
2  635.0
3  540.0
4  659.0
```

EDIT by comment:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['7280.0', '7330.0', '635.0', '540.0', np.nan, 'a']})
print (df)
        A
0  7280.0
1  7330.0
2   635.0
3   540.0
4     NaN
5       a

df.A = pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce')
print (df)
        A
0  7280.0
1  7330.0
2   635.0
3   540.0
4     NaN
5     NaN

df.A = df.A.mask( df.A // 1000 > 0, df.A // 10)
df.A = df.A.fillna(df.A.mean())
print (df)
       A
0  728.0
1  733.0
2  635.0
3  540.0
4  659.0
5  659.0
```

Comment: `df.A.mean()` is already the mean, why divide by `len(df.index)`?

Comment: You can actually do `df[df.A>1000]/=10` instead of the mask thing. And then `df.A.fillna(df.A.mean(), inplace=True)`.

Comment: @DYZ I have tried your approach, and I get the following error: TypeError: Could not operate 10 with block values unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: It seems first need `df.A = df.A.astype(float)` and if it failed  `df.A = pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce')` for convert bad values to numeric.

Comment: If values cannot be converted to numeric, are replaced by `NaN` because parameter `errors='coerce'`

Comment: I add sample to solution for second approach.

Comment: @M.M. I assumed your data was numeric, not string. It is not clear from your example.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution using `pandas.Series.apply()` and `pd.to_numeric()` functions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['A', 7280.0, 7330.0, 635.0, 540.0, 'NaN'])
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: int(str(x)[:-3]) if (isinstance(x, float) and len(repr(x)) == 6 and x % 10.0 == 0.0) else x)
df[df == 'NaN'] = pd.to_numeric(df[0], errors='coerce').mean()
print(df)
```

The output:

```
     0
0    A
1  728
2  733
3  635
4  540
5  659
```